# How to go about proving a condition for the greedy change-making algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, greedy

Recently I've been practicing a few change making algorithm questions and came across two conditions where we were tasked with finding out if the algorithms would produce an optimal solution for coins of each of the following denomination types for each condition. Following are the two separate conditions

[image]

How would we go about solving these two questions?

Comment: You haven't posted the problem statement. These are conditions/definitions but not problems. Also, as far as I know, there isn't a general method for proving greedy algorithms. You have to use different methods ad appropriate. I would always start by disproving it by finding a counter example. This is definitely much easier. And then start to prove it.

Comment: General Ghange-Making algorithm’s work for ***any*** set of positive weights (`x[1…n]`) and any sum, so there’s no need for a proof here.  The Greedy Method only works for all sums on “canonical” coin sets, and these do not look canonical to me.